# how to execute the query present as text in teradata

Tags: teradata

I have a table which a column contain select queries . can somebody help me on how to execute it without using SP.
Eg:

```
Table1:
Col1
---
Select * from tabl2 where id=1;
Select * from tabl2 where id=3;

enter code here
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use a SP?

Comment: I have created 3 volatile table , one is used in another and the third one contains the output but if i will go with SP then i am getting error that Temp1 does not exist while creating second volatile table in SP.

Comment: Replace PROCEDURE DB_Test.test()
Begin 
Create volatile Table Temp As 
( 
Select 
current_date as x 
) 
With data no primary index 
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS; 

-- Now reference the previous temp table to create a new temp table 
Create volatile Table NewTemp As 
( 
Select * FROM Temp 
) 
With data no primary index
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS; 
End

Comment: Your example works fine for me, what's your Teradata release?

Comment: Its teradata version :14.00.00.01

Comment: What if you create the VTs before the REPLACE PROCEDURE?

Comment: Ok I have created VTs before the SQL SP but since it is 'SELECT' clause so while i am executing the below SP it is throwing me error:- replace PROCEDURE DB_TEST.Test1()
BEGIN
DECLARE  P_SQL_TEXT     VARCHAR(10000);
DECLARE cursor_name CURSOR FOR SELECT * from Temp4;
OPEN cursor_name;
LOOP
FETCH  cursor_name into P_SQL_TEXT ;
CALL dbc.SysExecSQL (:P_SQL_TEXT);
END LOOP;
CLOSE cursor_name;
END;

Comment: I believe we cannot run the SELECT using dbc.SysExecSQL .Any alternative for that.

Comment: If you create VTs in a SP you must should drop them before you try to run the CREATE again (and catch an error using a CONTINUE HANDLER)

Comment: I have dropped it.
I have a table with select/ins/upd(DML) queries , how can i run it using sP .just a qucik sample anwers may be great help.

Comment: You open a FOR cursor on `select col1 from tab` and run each INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE using  DBC.SysExecSQL (or EXECUTE IMMEDIATE), to return the result of a SELECT it's a bit more syntax: http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1148_111A/ch05.140.53.html

Comment: Thanks dnoeth. I have done as you said and now my problem is solved.Just one more query , as you have mentioned the procedure that i have given you was working fine at your end, does it mean that we can not create a volatile table in sp and use it inside the sp using 14.00.00.01 ??

Comment: Of course you can use it, but maybe the handling of non-existing objects has changed between TD14 and TD15

Comment: Dnoeth, i just observed that it was a warning when i am running it through SQL assistant using ODBC connection.When i am calling the SP it is giving me correct result. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql @Query
```

to run your T-SQL

EDIT:
For Teradata :

```
CALL DBC.SysExecSQL(string_expression)
```

Comment: Your answer is MS SQL Server syntax, but this question is tagged `Teradata`.